# How to use binding sources to bind across multiple data tables?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datatable

Firstly, I would like to say I have searched the internet extensively and have not found anything on this topic.

My situation is that I have a junction table table in a SQL database (A table that just contains  a primary key and foreign keys to other tables). Now, it is this junction table that I actually wish to edit via win forms. Setting up a binding source to the junction table with a combo box  is no problem, however the user will only see primary/foreign key GUIDs when selecting data, obviously this is undesirable. The records which these foreign keys point to *do* have a "name" column, however they are on another table. So how can I have it so that when a user selects a record in the junction table in steady of the user seeing a  bunch of FK guids, the user will see the names associated with these records.

Lastly, notice the *binding* is really the key here. I can get the data inquestion (the names for the corresponding records) to populate a listbox/combobox no problem, the problem is when the user selects a record on the junction table, I need the other controls to reflect the change in selection. I think binding is the way to achieve that effect.

Sorry if my question is a little difficult to understand, it is difficult for me to explain it (I am still new to winforms myself).

Comment: I don't think you want to edit the junction table. How would you know its records are unique? You probably want to edit a collection of objects belonging to one object on the opposite side of the N:M association. So that would require some master-detail layout, where one detail record can belong to more than 1 master record. But maybe you can show your intended design. It's a bit hard to infer what you are trying.

Answer (score 0):

No middle (junction) table should bound to control since it is purely meant to achieve `many to many` relationship. Therefore, it is highly advisable to reconsider your scenario or design.

Comment: But is is the junction table that eventually needs to have records inserted/updated/deleted. How else can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your sqldatasource... i assume that your sqldatasource looks something like this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyDatabaseString %>"
                    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [ListOfFunFacts]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

If you want the names to show up than you need something like this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyDatabaseString %>"
                        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [ListOfFunFacts] a inner join Table2 b on  a.foreignkeyTable2 = b.Id"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: I really love this `asp` answer to a `winforms` question. Not to mention the usage of SQL stuff inside an HTML tag. EPIC. +1 totally. You should be my boss. You should be the owner of the company.